# Leaky-ReLU back propagation with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, backpropagation, relu

I wanted to implement the Leaky ReLU activation function with numpy (forward and backward pass) and wanted to get some comments about whether this implementation is correct.

So the Leaky ReLU(x) = `x if x > 0` and `alpha * x if x <= 0`.

This means, the derivative is: `1 if x > 0` and `alpha if x <= 0`.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np

alpha = 0.2
mask = None

def forward(x):
    global mask
    mask = x > 0
    ret = x
    ret[~mask] = ret[~mask] * alpha
    return ret

def backward(error):
    ret = np.ones(shape=error.shape)
    ret[~mask] = alpha
    ret = np.multiply(ret, error)
    return ret
```

And error is the tensor from the upper layer which is passed downward.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @erip I wanted some comments about whether this is correct.

Comment: I would prefer to avoid using global variables, as you could pass `x` to `backward` and just use `ret[x<=0] = alpha`.